# How to set UIScrollView's background image as a stretchable image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, stretch

I want to set UIScrollView's background image as a stretchable image. I tried:

```
UIImage* backgroundImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]
                               resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0) ];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

But it is not stretching.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of the resizable properties of the `UIImage`, you need to use an `UIImageView`. As you've noticed, it doesn't work if you set it as a background color. Just create an `UIImageView` and put it behind your `UIScrollView` with the same frame if it has to be fixed, or inside your `UIScrollView` with the same size as the `contentSize` if you want it to scroll...

Answer (score 1):

Add image in `UIImageView` and in your case set

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

you can set it to any of the following

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
UIViewContentModeRedraw,
UIViewContentModeCenter,
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight
```

Ans add This `UIImageView` in you `scrolView`.

Another way is you can use following method for get/create image size as you want.

Use following method with specific **hight** and **width** with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UIImage* backgroundImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.jpg"]
                           resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0) ];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[backgroundImage drawInRect:self.scrollView.bounds];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```